# How to pad strings with spaces in a Unix shell script?

Tags: unix, shell-script

I have data that looks like this:

```
01234567
09876544
12345676
34576980
```

I need to pad this with 11 spaces i.e. my output should look like this:

```
'           01234567' 
'           09876544'
'           12345676'
'           34576980'
```

How can I do it using UNIX shell scripting?

Comment: Does your input literally look like this, in one line? How many fields are there? Only two or more? Is this in a text file, and are there more lines than one? What about the spacing between the quotes and the comma, are those to be inserted as well? If you say Unix do you mean UNIX, strictly, or Linux as well? What scripting language? Is Bash okay, or others? Please [edit] and clarify your question. Maybe you can tell us more about the background, because what you're asking for seems a little contrived.

Comment: There's a live preview how your post will look like afterwards while you're editing. Please use it.

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming/guessing that the apostrophes are not supposed to be included in the output.

Standard shell solution, where `infile` is the file containing the input:

```
while read i; do printf "%19s\n" "$i"; done < infile
```

where `19` is the string length per row as they are given (8) plus the wanted padding (11). I'm again guessing that this kind of padding is what you want, and not just prepending 11 spaces to all lines. If this is not the case, you need to give a specific example of how input rows of differing length should be handled.

If the apostrophes were meant to be included:

```
while read i; do printf "'%19s'\n" "$i"; done < infile
```

Answer (score 6):

A shorter option from GNU coreutils is the `pr` command:

```
pr -T -o 11 foo.txt
```

Excerpt from man page:

```
DESCRIPTION
       Paginate or columnate FILE(s) for printing.

       -o, --indent=MARGIN
              offset each line with MARGIN (zero) spaces

       -T, --omit-pagination
              omit page headers and trailers, eliminate any pagination by form feeds set in input files
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ex-editor (Vi), either by changing the file in-place:

```
ex -s +"%s@^@    @" -cwq foo.txt
```

or by parsing the standard input and print it into standard output:

```
cat foo.txt | ex -s +"%s@^@    @" +%p -cq! /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in a text file:

```
    $ cat file.txt 
    01234567
    09876544
    12345676
    34576980
```

Use sed command or a Perl one-liner as follows:

```
    $ sed -n "s#^\(.*\)#\'           \1\'#p" file.txt
    '           01234567'
    '           09876544'
    '           12345676'
    '           34576980'

-n :    By default, each line of input is echoed to the standard output after 
        all of the commands have been applied to it.  The -n option suppresses
        this behavior.
 p :    Print the current pattern space.


    $ perl -p -e "s#^(.*)#\'           \$1\'#" file.txt
    '           01234567'
    '           09876544'
    '           12345676'
    '           34576980'

−p: Assumes an input loop around the script. Lines are printed.
−e commandline:
May be used to enter a single line of script. Multiple −e commands
build up a multiline script.
```

I have tried these commands on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score -1):

This is a supplyment to @Daniel Andersson's answer, in case the length of each line read from a file varies, you can do as following:

```
while read i; do printf "%11s%s\n" "" "$i"; done < infile
```

Comment: Why is there a comma?

Comment: Please add some explanation  (compare to the other answers).

Comment: @Scott, Daniel Andersson's answer assumes each line of the file has same the length (8 digits), so he uses %19s, in case the length varies, we can use the %11s%s, right?

Comment: @confetti sorry, it's a typo, answer updated

Comment: When referring to "padding" one usually wants the output to be a fixed width. E.g. 19 characters. If the input is lower than that, "padding" usually refers to adding a space (or 0, or whatever) to the left (or right) to the input in order to achieve the desired character length of the output.

Comment: @confetti I think the questioner just wants to add 11 whitespaces to the left, if so, how can we achieve this if the length of each line in the input text file is different?